# SharePoint 2013 - Load JavaScript or CSS file only if not in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, css, edit

From a custom page layout, for a publishing site collection, how can I tell SharePoint 2013 to display...

```
<script>
console.log('this should display in non-edit window');
</script>
```

...that loads in the `<head>` of the page **if I am not edit mode (i.e. editing a publishing page)**?

If I am in edit mode, I should not even see the above script, not even in view source mode.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put your script inside an [EditModePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.editmodepanel.aspx) control. Setting the [PageDisplayMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.editmodepanel.pagedisplaymode.aspx) property determines when it shows on the page.

I use them for setting different CSS on a page layout during editing and they would be perfect in your scenario. Look at some of the OOTB page layouts for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on this approah! I totally forgot